# Best way to implement a user skills method - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

So my problem is more or less as follows. I have a rails applications with the following classes:

- Users
- Skills

Each user can have multiple skills and they are added from the users profile screen which is the show action for the users controller. Currently I have the Skills set up and able to be created but I cannot add a pre-built skill onto a users profile, I'm not sure if I need to add a new action in the Users controller or if I just need to use the update action from the Skills controller. My ideal solution would be for the admin user (already created and sorted this out) to go on to the users profile and add the skills but I have absolutely no idea how to implement this. My controllers, models etc are as follows:

skills_controller.rb

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_skill, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /skills
  # GET /skills.json
  def index
    @skills = Skill.all
  end

  # GET /skills/1
  # GET /skills/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /skills/new
  def new
    @skill = Skill.new
  end

  # GET /skills/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /skills
  # POST /skills.json
  def create
    @skill = Skill.new(skill_params)
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @skill.save
        format.html { redirect_to @skill, notice: 'Skill was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @skill }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @skill.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /skills/1
  # PATCH/PUT /skills/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @skill.update(skill_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @skill, notice: 'Skill was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @skill }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @skill.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /skills/1
  # DELETE /skills/1.json
  def destroy
    @skill.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to skills_url, notice: 'Skill was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_skill
      @skill = Skill.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def skill_params
      params.require(:skill).permit(:name, :badge_url, :user_id)
    end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @group_options = Group.all.map{|g| [ g.name, g.id] }
    @subunit_options = Subunit.all.map{|s| [ s.name, s.id] }
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at ASC')
  end

  def chf_index
    @chf = User.where(group_id: 1).paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at ASC')
  end

  def rmc_index
    @rmc = User.where(group_id: 2).paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at ASC')
  end

  def ra_index
    @ra = User.where(group_id: 3).paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at ASC')
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_training_events = User.find(params[:id]).training_events.to_a
    @event_id = TrainingEvent.where(user_ids: @user.id).all
    @group = Group.find(@user.group_id)
    if @user.subunit_id.nil?
    else
      @subunit = Subunit.find(@user.subunit_id)
    end
    @current_user_id = current_user.id
    if @user.rank_id.nil?
    else
      @rank = Rank.find(@user.rank_id)
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @subunit_options = Subunit.all.map{|s| [ s.name, s.id] }
    @group_options = Group.all.map{|g| [ g.name, g.id] }
  end


  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @subunit_options = Subunit.all.map{|s| [ s.name, s.id] }
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    # Decides which parameters can be passed to user creation
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :group_id, :subunit_id, :rank_id,     :training_event_id, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
    end



end
```

skill.rb

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save   :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest

    belongs_to :group
    has_many :ranks
    has_many :skills
    has_many :mission_notes
    has_and_belongs_to_many :training_events
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills

    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :group_id, presence: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
    def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                      BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

    # Returns a random token.
    def User.new_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
    def remember
        self.remember_token = User.new_token
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
    end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
    def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
        BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
    end

    # Forgets a user.
    def forget
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
    end

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
    def authenticated?(attribute, token)
        digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
        return false if digest.nil?
        BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
    end

    # Activates an account.
      def activate
        update_attribute(:activated,    true)
        update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
      end

      # Sends activation email.
      def send_activation_email
        UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver
      end

      # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end


end
```

and finally routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :skills

  resources :subunits

  resources :mission_notes

  resources :training_events

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  root "categories#index"
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  get 'dynamic' => 'subunits#dynamic'

  get 'chf_index'  => 'users#chf_index'
  get 'rmc_index'  => 'users#rmc_index'
  get 'ra_index'  => 'users#ra_index'
  resources :categories, :has_many => :notes
  resources :notes
  resources :users do
    resources :skills
  end
  resources :ranks
  resources :groups

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

end
```

Let me know if you need additional information

**Edit**
Added the following as my function definition

```
def add_skill_to_user
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.skills.create(skill_params) #skill name, level...
    @skills_options = Skill.all.map{|s| [ s.name, s.id] }
    #whatever happens when this is is done, redirect, json answer etc...
    if user.skills.update_all(skill_params)
      flash[:success] = "Skill Added"
    else
       render 'add_skill_to_user'
    end
  end

  private
    # Set skills params whitelist    
    def skill_params
      params.permit(:name, :user_id)
    end
```

and the following to routes

```
post 'users/:id/add_skill_to_user' => 'users#add_skill_to_user'
```

And this is my form

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "users", action: "add_skill_to_user"}, method: "put") do %>
    <%= collection_select(:skill, :name, Skill.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<%end%>
```

I now can't submit the form with a skill name and skill id as I receive this error `Empty list of attributes to change`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a method that will search for the user, and then add the skills.

```
def add_skill_to_user
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  user.skills.create(skill_params) #skill name, level...
  #whatever happens when this is is done, redirect, json answer etc...
end
```

Then create the routes, and the form in the view which accepts sends the user name and the skill info.

That should be enough.

EDITED:

As per the form:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

```
form_tag({controller: "admin", action: "set_user_skill"}, method: "post(or put)") Then the form... and the submit button.
```

Comment: And would I want to do this is in User or Skills controller, looks to me like it should be User but I could be wrong

Comment: If you have an admin controllers the place is there. If not, as it is a user modifying method, set it to the user.

Comment: Ok I've got routes set, the action is there now I just need to set the form, the problem I have is when I put `<% simple_form_for(user) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<%end%>` I get an undefined variable error on the user part, which controller should the form be for?

Comment: You have to create a form that sends the user name(perhaps from a dropdown) and the skill properties(or just the name). Edited:
form_tag({controller: "adming", action: "set_user_skill"}, method: "post(or put)")
Then the form... and the submit button.

Comment: Ok now can't submit the form, have updated my original question with the new code and issues, cheers for the help with this

Comment: I recommend you to create a new question with the user form problem. As this one is called: Best way to implement something. I will be happy to answer this new question in the new thread.